# Why does vagrant use 2 ssh private keys?

Tags: vagrant

What is the difference between the private key located at `~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key` and the `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key` that is located in the same directory as my `Vagrantfile`? Why the need for both? How do I use one or the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Public boxes are shipped with the `insecure key` which is always the same, shipped with vagrant and located in `~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`.

This allow vagrant to use ssh on the first vagrant up.

Then (still on the first run) vagrant check the configuration key `config.ssh.insert_key`, and if it's set to `true`(which is the default, it replace it by a generated one, typically located in `<current_directory>/.vagrant/machines/<machine_name>/<provider>/private_key`.

*Notice that the directory structure implied that you have one key per machine and per provider so multiple machine/provider in the same vagrant environment end up with different keys.*

For this point on, every connection on that machine will use the same **generated key** until you destroy it, and the process will be reproduce in the next **first vagrant up**. This behaviour is standard and implicit for most use cases.

However since one [can create his own custom box](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/boxes.html), one can either:

1. Add the `insecure key` in the box, so the process is the same as for public boxes.
2. Add a custom public key in the box, then set the `config.ssh.private_key_path` to the corresponding private key.

But as the [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html#available-settings) says:

> You can also specify multiple private keys by setting this to be an array. This is useful, for example, if you use the default private key to bootstrap the machine, but replace it with perhaps a more secure key later.

So you can actually mix both behaviour.

A common use case is when a company or team require(for whatever reason) each user to connect to the machine with is real ssh key.

One solution is to use the `insecure key` as default and switch to user key on the first up:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.ssh.private_key_path = [
    '~/.ssh/id_rsa',
    '~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key'
  ]
  config.vm.provision 'file', 
    source: '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub', 
    destination: '~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
end
```

But you can also replace the `vagrant insecure key` with a company/team default key, then swith in a same way to user specific key.

**Anyhow when not using the `vagrant insecure key` one must ensure the first provisioner to run is always the one replacing the key**.

Comment: Thank you for that very detailed answer

Comment: Glad to help :). I spend quit some time understanding those kind of features and behaviours on Vagrant, which has amazing defaults but lack explicitness on some not so irrelevant en useful details, especially when it doesn't work like you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer useful but did not work in my case as default private key is with the box.

Hence following was used:

```
$own_ssh_key = <<-SCRIPT
ssh-keygen -q -t ed25519 -N "" -f .ssh/login_ssh
cp .ssh/login_ssh.pub .ssh/authorized_keys 
cp .ssh/login_ssh /vagrant/.
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.private_key_path = [File.expand_path("../login_ssh", __FILE__)] + 
      Dir.glob("#{Dir.home}/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-*-kinetic64/*/virtualbox/vagrant_insecure_key")

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $own_ssh_key, privileged: false
end
```